# Rows to one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have sql query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
    @EndDate    DATETIME;

SELECT   @StartDate = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)        
    ,@EndDate   = getdate();


SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)), 0),112),6) AS MonthName --LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)), 0),112),6)
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x
WHERE   x.type = 'P'        
AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate)`
```

i need to do it in this format:

201901, 201902

Thanks

Comment: what is your dbms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the older version of SQL Server, you can try like following.

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
    @EndDate    DATETIME;

SELECT   @StartDate = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)        
    ,@EndDate   = getdate();

;with cte as
(
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)), 0),112),6) AS MonthName 
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x
WHERE   x.type = 'P'        
AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate)
)

SELECT  DISTINCT 
            STUFF ((
                SELECT ', ' + [MonthName]
                FROM 
                cte
                ORDER BY [MonthName]
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ),1,2,'' )
            AS [MonthName]
```

For SQL Server 2017+, you can use `STRING_AGG` like following.

```
select STRING_AGG (MonthName, ',') as MonthName
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below query:

Select (Stuff((Select ', ' + cast(eid as varchar(10)) From employee FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,''))